# Data loss on my login page?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason inputs in my login page don't seem to be getting processes correctly. Correct user inputs are getting returned as invalid (wrong password) having had a look through, I can't see anything particularly obvious. But I can only assume the username or password isn't getting passed for some reason. Would someone more experienced be able to take a look and suggest how I can put it right. Thanks guys. P.S My form is OK, so not included.

```
function logcon($user, $password )
{

   $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $user);
   $esc_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn,$password);  
$sql = "SELECT * from USERS WHERE username  ='{$user}' AND password='{$password}'";
 $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);


              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            return $row;
            }
```

Login page.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$user=$_POST['user']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];


//To ensure that none of the fields are blank when submitting the form if
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
    {    


$user = stripslashes($user);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$db1=new dbmember();
$db1->openDB();           
$row=$db1->logcon($user, $password);


if($row[0]==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
    header("location:index.php");
}
        else
        {
            print ('<div id="error">Acess denied, wrong username or password?</div>');
        }
        }
        else
            {
            print ('<div id="error">Enter something!</div>');
        }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use your [**other account**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2633799/downvotemeeee)? I kinda liked the name

Comment: Because of the haters on here downvoting for LuLz. Use your common sense. :)

Comment: manual escaping? with mysqli? You really should be using placeholders.

Comment: This is actually *least* problem with this code...

Comment: Plaintext? Oh yes....I meant SHA512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using the wrong variable name in your query. I would also suggest you look into doing some sort of hashing and salting of your passwords instead of saving them as plain text.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from USERS WHERE username  ='{$user}' AND password='{$password}'";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * from USERS WHERE username  ='{$user}' AND password='{$esc_password}'";
```

And your conditional check seems off, you are checking to see if the first field in the results is = 1 instead of seeing if there is a return.

```
if($row[0]==1)
```

Should probably be

```
if($row)
```